# Rails 4: cannot create a new instance of model associated with this model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, constructor, associations, has-many

I have a Rails App which has a Model called "Service" which has an association with another model called "Upload". A Service has_many Uploads and an Upload belongs_to Service.
Uploads is a model that is using the paperclip gem to model an uploaded file.

Here are the Model classes for both:

---

service.rb:

```
         # == Schema Information
         #
         # Table name: services
         #
         #  id            :integer          not null, primary key
         #  created_at    :datetime
         #  updated_at    :datetime
         #  last_run_time :datetime
         #  name          :string(255)
         #  description   :text
         #
  class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
       attr_accessor :name, :description
       has_many :uploads
     end
```

---

upload.rb

```
       # == Schema Information
       #
       # Table name: uploads
       #
       #  id                      :integer          not null, primary key
       #  created_at              :datetime
       #  updated_at              :datetime
       #  sourcedata_file_name    :string(255)
       #  sourcedata_content_type :string(255)
       #  sourcedata_file_size    :integer
       #  sourcedata_updated_at   :datetime
       #  service_id              :integer
       #

     class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_attached_file :sourcedata
      belongs_to :service

      end
```

My constructor methods using rails associations dont seem to be working.

When I run this at rails console I see the following:

> > s = Service.new

```
 => #<Service id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, last_run_time: nil, name: nil, description: nil>


  >> > @u = s.upload.new

  NoMethodError: undefined method `upload' for #<Service:0x007fc4c7818470>

  >>@u = s.create_upload()

  NoMethodError: undefined method `create_upload' for #<Service:0x007fc4c7818470>

 >>@u = s.uploads.build

  NoMethodError: undefined method `uploads' for #<Service:0x007fc4c7818470>

 >> @u = s.uploads.create

 NoMethodError: undefined method `uploads' for #<Service:0x007fc4c7818470>
```

I tried to create the associated model instance using these methods and it doesn't seem to be working. Im wondering what am I doing wrong.
Could someone help me please.

Thanks

---

s.inspect =

```
   => "#<Service id: 6, created_at: \"2013-11-27 16:41:43\", updated_at: \"2013-11-27 16:41:43\", 
   last_run_time: nil, name: nil, description: nil>"
```

Comment: could you print the result of s.inspect ?

Comment: could you check the result of s.methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
s.uploads.build
```

and

```
s.uploads.create
```

You can read about what methods are available here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference

> 4.3.1 Methods Added by has_many
>
> When you declare a has_many association, the declaring class
>   automatically gains 13 methods related to the association:

```
collection(force_reload = false)
collection<<(object, ...)
collection.delete(object, ...)
collection.destroy(object, ...)
collection=objects
collection_singular_ids
collection_singular_ids=ids
collection.clear
collection.empty?
collection.size
collection.find(...)
collection.where(...)
collection.exists?(...)
collection.build(attributes = {}, ...)
collection.create(attributes = {})
```

Comment: Try closing out your session and starting it over. Or try using `reload!`.

Comment: Tried it. No effect. Service just doesn't seem to have the uploads connection

Comment: You've got something else going on in your application that is causing problems. Install `pry-rails` and do `show-method Service`.

Comment: I have pry installed. On which model or where should I call this method show-method Service. In the console?

Comment: Yea, the console will show you the evaluated source code for `Service`.

Comment: This is a sign of something much worse.. You should probably post your app to github so others can help.

Comment: As it turns out it was the name of the model: "Service". I created another model with the name "Task" and exactly the same functionality and everything was wrking. Reallys strange since Service is not a reserved word. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
s.uploads.build 
s.uploads.create
```

Comment: Thanks but uploads doesnot exist as a method.

Comment: If you define `has_many :uploads`, it defines the method with the same name. If it does not, something is wrong. Are you sure you reloaded the server/restarted console after adding the association?

Comment: It was the name of the model: "Service" that was cauasing the problem

Comment: I see, these kind of things are usually very nasty and its consequences are very confusing. I'm glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `has_many`, so the `upload` method does not exist because you have many of them...

Use `s.uploads.new` (or `s.uploads.build`) or `s.uploads.create` and read the ActiveRecord documentation.

Comment: My Service doesnot have any method called uploads. Really strange